# From IIS ID To Sitename

Tags: c#, iis

I'm making a simple C# desktop application that searches into the log directories to get the  weight of logs for every site. This is the easy part, but now I'd like to make my life easier by getting the site name from the ID.

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you use the IIS 7? If so, you can use Microsoft.Web.Administrator.dll to achieve your goal. Please try to review the following articles on MSDN. I hope it can be helpful to you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms613523(v=VS.90).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager_members(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: Not at the moment, we'll migrating all IIS 6 to 7 in a while... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a question... Where can I find the namespace Microsoft.Web?